# A specific record in a table causes table to hang

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've just run into a table that I can't delete the contents of suddenly.
`SELECT` and `DELETE` operations on this table hang, but if I abort the `SELECT` I get some of the rows returned (29, to be exact).

I tested using `SELECT TOP N` and found a point after which the query hangs.

```
select  top 37 [Id] from [foo]
go

select  top 38 [Id] from [foo]
go
```

results in this: (Timeout of 5 minutes)
[image: Output]

The execution plans:
[image: Exec Plans]

The Index is on the Id column which is the primary key.

Is there any way I can delete the contents of the table? I haven't tried using `TRUNCATE TABLE` yet.

Comment: You mean top 37 work, but top 38 doesnt?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yep, exactly that. Top 37 returns 37 rows. Top 38 hangs.

Comment: how many rows are in your table? We need much more information so we can try reproduce the problem, otherwise will be a guessing game.

Comment: can you post execution plans xml in a link

Comment: @TheGameiswar Usually is better if you include a link showing how to do it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - According to sys.dm_db_partition_stats, 38

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan

Comment: I dont have idea what can be. I suggest you try SELECT without top. Trying to create a new table with `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`...

Comment: @TheGameiswar http://pastebin.com/7UnqRdAb - Top 37

http://pastebin.com/7PVJ5J19 - Top 38

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Select without top also hangs

Comment: Something's probably got a row-lock. Look at the activity monitor while your query is running, it should show blocking/blocked queries. As a quick hack, you could restart SQL Server.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Not sure what was locking it, but killing the head process cleared it up. I think it might've been an incomplete insert, since now it works, but there's only 37 rows in the table.

Comment: Run the select and  run below query as well in parallel and update the question:select 
txt.text,ec.blocking_session_id,ec.last_wait_type,ec.wait_type from sys.dm_exec_requests ec
cross apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec.sql_handle) txt
where session_id=<<session id from where your are running select >>

Comment: can you try using nolock with select query?. There could be many reason for this error.